# Why can't I connect my Iphone 4 to our home Wifi?

Tags: wifi, iphone

Umm, I need help about my Iphone 4... I recently bought it and was able to connect to our home wifi perfectly.. But one day, we don't know why, but me and my brother's iphone 4 was unable to connect to the home wifi. Although, we could connect to our school and other places's wifi network except our home wifi!!! :( Help please??? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any information for us about your home network, router, settings ect.. Do you even see it in the scan?

Comment: some times it helped me to just reboot the wifi-router.

Answer (score 1):

A few years back I had a particular wireless access point that would often exhibit this behaviour. One or two devices wouldn't connect after some time (a few days, maybe a week). Rebooting it let everyone back on.

- Try rebooting the access point.
- Check for driver/firmware updates (access point and devices).
- If you can, borrow or swap access points temporarily to see if its any better.

It seemed, in our case, to be a bug in the router, but never really figured out if it was randomly 'breaking' for certain clients/chipsets/etc or if it was something more consistent like a bug in the 802.11n compliance... in the end we replaced it and all was fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Network Settings. It will forget all the networks you have been connected to and treat each one as new. Then you may choose your network and type the correct password to connect to the internet.

It worked for me that way.

Comment: Settings->general->reset->reset network settings worked like a charm for me!

Answer (score -2):

Halo My name is anonymous heheehehe Im a technical support of a DSL we received a lot of issues like that their iphones and ipads or tablets or laptops are cant connect to the home DSL wifi. It is all bout compatibility of all Wifi Security of each devices most or all of the wifi devices are compatible with WEP wifi security. All you need to do is to access your modem like 192.168.1.10 from there change the wifi security from WPA/WPA2 to WEP then it asks you to change your wifi password. Or contact your DSL provider. Hope this can help you guys :) .

Comment: This is not good advice for a couple of reasons. 1. WEP is not more compatible with iPhones/iPads than WPA/WPA2. 2. WEP is less secure than WPA/WPA2. There is little reason to use WEP these days.

Answer (score -2):

Just try rebooting your router..that's the only thing that worked for me!